# Magnific Pop up for Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, magnific-popup

I have been trying to figure this out for the past couple of hours, but how do I integrate the plugin into a wordpress site?

Because the plugin itself does not have a specific directory to be placed, I am confused as to where the files need to be put in order for it to work. My explanation is pretty vague, as I haven't been able to upload any of the 3 files mentioned into wordpress as of yet.

so there are 3 files: 
jquery.magnific-popup.js/ jquery.magnific-popup.min.js/ magnific-popup.css

The end product i need is essentially just a set of gallery items, not restricted by width or height, so I am able to have a website similar to this one here as reference: http://www.three-d-conceptwerke.com/

Each Gallery item opens a pop up that displays several images within each gallery, in which case each item is treated as a project containing several images.

That aside, without knowing how to integrate the files into wordpress, I am unable to work on it. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you place them - just call the scripts and stylesheets in your header or add them into your functions.php.

E.g. if I uploaded them into a directory called external-plugins, I would just call them as

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/external-plugins/magnific-popup.css"> <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

And add your arguments below. Should work fine in your header.php

**Edit:** That link you posted pretty much explains everything you need to do - if you can't follow it, maybe you should hire somebody else to do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are pretty clear from the link you provided...

> Create the directory **magnific-popup** in your **theme’s directory**. Download the MP CSS and JS files from GitHub and **put both in the magnific-popup directory**

You need either use an FTP client like Filezilla or use a File Manager from your hosting control panel to log into your site's file directory.  Once you are there, navigate to your WordPress theme's directory wp-content/themes/your-theme/ and create a new directory named **magnific-popup**.  Then upload your 3 files into that directory and follow the rest of the instructions to finish setting up your popup.

If you've found this helpful please mark this as the acceptable answer to your question.